# Snail game: creating boundaries

Tags: c++

I'm programming a game that allows an user to move a snail along a 2d vector. The snail leaves a trail behind. I am trying to data sanitize it so the snail can only move in that 2d vector. However, after asking the user to reinput a move after telling them they can't go out of bounds, the userinput quiestion appears twice before allowing the snail to move again.

I was wondering if someone could tell me why this is happening.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

        int num3,num4;

        cout<< "please enter the length and width respectively: ";
        cin>>num3>> num4;

        vector<vector<string>> vec( num3 , vector<string> (num4, " "));
        vec[0][0] = "@";
        for(int i = 0; i < num3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < num4; j++){
                cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
                }
            cout<< endl;
        }
    char move = '\0';
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        while(move != 'q'){
            cout << "Enter the direction (w/a/s/d): ";
            cin >> move;
            if(move == 'd'){
                if(((y + 1) >= 0) && ((y + 1) <= num3 - 1)){
                    vec[x][y] = "_";
                    y = y+1;
                    vec[x][y] = "@";
                    for(int i = 0; i < num3; i++){
                        for(int j = 0; j < num4; j++){
                            cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
                            }
                        cout<< endl;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    cout << "that is out of bounds";
                    cout << "Enter the direction (w/a/s/d): ";
                    cin >> move;
                }
            }

            else if(move == 'a'){
                if(((y - 1) >= 0) && ((y - 1) <= num3 - 1)){
                    vec[x][y] = "_";
                    y = y-1;
                    vec[x][y] = "@";
                    for(int i = 0; i < num3; i++){
                        for(int j = 0; j < num4; j++){
                            cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
                            }
                        cout<< endl;
                        
                    }
                }
                else{
                    cout << "that is out of bounds";
                    cout << "Enter the direction (w/a/s/d): ";
                    cin >> move;
                }
            }
            else if(move == 'w'){
                if(((x - 1) >= 0) && ((x - 1) <= num4 - 1)){
                    vec[x][y] = "_";
                    x = x-1;
                    vec[x][y] = "@";
                    for(int i = 0; i < num3; i++){
                        for(int j = 0; j < num4; j++){
                            cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
                            }
                        cout<< endl;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    cout << "that is out of bounds";
                    cout << "Enter the direction (w/a/s/d): ";
                    cin >> move; 
                }
            }
            else if(move == 's'){
                if(((x + 1) >= 0) && ((x + 1) <= num4 - 1)){
                    vec[x][y] = "_";
                    x = x+1;
                    vec[x][y] = "@";
                    for(int i = 0; i < num3; i++){
                        for(int j = 0; j < num4; j++){
                            cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
                            }
                        cout<< endl;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    cout << "that is out of bounds";
                    cout << "Enter the direction (w/a/s/d): ";
                    cin >> move;    
                }
            }
            else if(move == 'q'){
                break;

            }
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are outputting it twice. First, right after the while, which I would keep. Second, after every `"that is out of bounds";` you print it too. Also you are asking for input twice.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: [OT]: sub-function might help to avoid copy-paste: as `printMap(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>&)`

Answer (score 0):

The bug lies in `else` part. In your case, when it is out of bounds, it will first executes following statements.

```
cout << "that is out of bounds";
cout << "Enter the direction (w/a/s/d): ";
cin >> move;
```

Then it will reenter the while loop and following statements will be executed unless the move is 'q'.

```
cout << "Enter the direction (w/a/s/d): ";
cin >> move;
```

Therefore, users will be asked to enter direction twice. You can delete `cout << "Enter the direction (w/a/s/d): "; cin >> move;`  in the `else` part.